# Извлечение подстрок

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо извлечь определённые части строки. Пример:

```
"Суббота" => "Суббота"
"Суббота02окт" => "Суббота", "02", "окт"
"Суббота02окт." => "Суббота", "02", "окт"
```

Если в конце строки есть точка, то она должна быть проигнорирована. Пробовал реализовать это так:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'([А-Я][А-Яа-я]+)([0-9]+)([А-Я][А-Яа-я]+)')
date_result = re.findall(pattern, date)
```

Но получаю пустой массив, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы ищете целый паттерн `слово-цифры-слово`, а нужно `слово ИЛИ цифры`. Для этого используйте знак `|`:

```py
import re
dates = ["Суббота", "Суббота02окт", "Суббота02окт."]
pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]+|[А-ЯЁа-яё]+')
for date in dates:
    print(re.findall(pattern, date))
# ['Суббота']
# ['Суббота', '02', 'окт']
# ['Суббота', '02', 'окт']
```

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос решён :)

Answer (score 0):

Не так: обязательное наличие трёх частей и обязательные заглавные буквы в третьей части.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'([А-Я][А-Яа-я]+)([0-9]+)*([А-Яа-я]+)*')
```

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос решён :)